# Missing 64 bit support

Tags: ios, app-store, 64-bit

This is driving me insane as i have tried everything i can think of and read.

I am getting the following error when uploading to appstore:

[image]

My settings are set as:

[image]

When archiving, i do not have a physical device attached (i.e. i am using the generic device option).

I don't know what else to try!

Answer (score 0):

OK so this was weird... despite my settings being correct (as per the above screenshot) when i search for armv7, it took me to the same 'valid architectures' line which did not have arm64...

Anyway adding that in worked and now validates.

Mental.